# WSO2: Stream Processor

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

How can i configure @sink to call a soap based web api? where can i specify the soap action? reference i found online aren't working properly?

```
    @sink(type='http',publisher.url='http://localhost:8009/foo', method='{POST}',headers="'content-type:xml','content-length:94'", client.bootstrap.configuration="'client.bootstrap.socket.timeout:20', 'client.bootstrap.worker.group.size:10'", client.pool.configuration="'client.connection.pool.count:10','client.max.active.connections.per.pool:1'", @map(type='xml', @payload('{<events>
    <event>
        <symbol>WSO2</symbol>
        <price>55.6</price>
        <volume>100</volume>
    </event>
</events>,
POST,
Content-Length:24#Content-Location:USA#Retry-After:120}')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example configuration how you can invoke SOAP endpoint. Here we are utilizing [HTTP sink](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/1.0.41/) with [XML source mapper](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-map-xml/api/4.0.21/). Hope this fulfill your requirement.

```
@App:name("SiddhiAppSOAPTest")
@App:description("Description of the plan")

-- Please refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Quick+Start+Guide on getting started with SP editor. 

define stream inputStream(attr1 int);

@sink(type='http', publisher.url='http://localhost:8280/services/echo', method='POST',headers="'Content-Type:text/xml','SOAPAction:urn:echoInt'",
@map(type='xml', enclosing.element="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:echo='http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>",
    @payload( "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><echo:echoInt><in>{{attr1}}</in></echo:echoInt></soapenv:Body>")
)
)
define stream outputStream (attr1 int);

from inputStream
select *
insert into outputStream;
```

As you can observe I have defined SOAPAction as a HTTP header and also the Content-Type.

Comment: Hi Tishan

This works fine for me, thank you very much for your support