# Call http web service from siddhi file

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I need to call a web service from my siddhi file.
in my case isn't important waiting the response, i would call external http service and stop.

I have tried with http(sink) and http-request(sink) like doc:
https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/2.0.5/#http-sink

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use HTTP sink if you want to do a fire and forget request. This [testcase](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-io-http/blob/master/component/src/test/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/io/http/sink/HttpSinkTestCase.java#L118) will help you in writing one. Also please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061131/wso2-stream-processor) SO question. It is for making a SOAP request using HTTP sink.

Comment: Hi Tushan, i tried to run this code:
define stream inputStream(attr1 int);

@sink(type='http', publisher.url='http://localhost:6663/testTarget', method='GET',headers="'Content-Type:application/json'",
    @map(type='json'))
define stream outputStream (attr1 int);

from inputStream
select *
insert into outputStream;

But it dosn't run in my case
Can you help me?

Comment: Hi Davide, Sorry for the delay in answering this. Will you be able to open a ticket in Siddhi Github project to track this as is a specific case to you. Please provide your Siddhi application and error you are getting